# « Avance sexuelle », « proposition sexuelle », « demande de faveur sexuelle » ou « sollicitation de faveur sexuelle »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Contexte (conseil à un ami)

Cesse de lui faire des **avances sexuelles**, ça fait plusieurs fois que tu lui demandes si tu peux lui faire une fellation et qu’il la refuse. Je pense honnêtement que tu le poursuis de tes assiduités et que la situation frise le harcèlement sexuel.

Cesse de lui faire des **propositions sexuelles**, ça fait plusieurs fois que tu lui demandes si tu peux lui faire une fellation et qu’il la refuse. Je pense honnêtement que tu le poursuis de tes assiduités et que la situation frise le harcèlement sexuel.

Cesse de lui demander des faveurs sexuelles/faire des **demandes de faveurs sexuelles**, ça fait plusieurs fois que tu lui demandes si tu peux lui faire une fellation qu’il refuse. Je pense honnêtement que tu le poursuis de tes assiduités et que la situation frise le harcèlement sexuel.

Cesse de **solliciter ses faveurs sexuelles**, ça fait plusieurs fois que tu lui demandes si tu peux lui faire une fellation qu’il refuse. Je pense honnêtement que tu le poursuis de tes assiduités et que la situation frise le harcèlement sexuel.

Les refontes sont les bienvenues!

Comment: Franchement, je trouve tout ça de trop. J'ai du mal à imaginer cette conversation entre qui que se soit. Et surtout le tu avec ce langage "haut de gamme".

Comment: @Lambie Au Québec, le tutoiement est la norme entre amis.

Comment: J’ai ajouté de l’information pour éclaircir le contexte.

Comment: Je comprends en revanche votre point de vue.

Comment: Mais je ne parle pas de ça. Entre amis, on parle de façon plus relâchée et pas avec des tournures si emberlificotées. Par ailleurs, vous ne croyez pas qu'à cette hauteur du championnat, ne pas comprendre le tutoiement serait un peu bizarre?

Comment: @Lambie Qu’auriez-vous dit alors, Lambie ?

Comment: De façon plus relâchée.

Comment: Et bien, faire ou tailler la pipe, bien sûr...

Comment: Ce qui donnerait, reviendrait à dire au final (avec toute la chair autour)…

Comment: Vouloir faire une pipe constitue-t-il une avance sexuelle, une proposition sexuelle ou une demande de faveur sexuelle?

Comment: Je me pose la question car c’est celui qui demande qui donne, et non l’inverse, celui qui bénéficie du plaisir physique, qui subit, c’est l’autre.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137293/discussion-between-lambie-and-therese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si je comprends bien la question, qui n'est qu'implicite, il s'agit de déterminer laquelle, des quatre possibilité convient du point de vue sens.

Il y a tout d'abord un choix à faire entre « proposition » et « avance », et il est clair à mon avis si l'on se base sur la définition de ces termes dans le TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propositions)) − Au plur. [En parlant d'un homme] *Faire des propositions.* **Proposer des relations sexuelles à un partenaire.** Faire des propositions galantes, impertinentes.
> • La nuit, me dit-elle (...) n'a pas été bonne. Il a discouru, il a chanté (...) et il m'a fait des propositions. Je n'en suis pas offensée (A. France, Rôtisserie, 1893, p.348)
> • ... comme mes parents me reprochaient ma paresse et de n'avoir pas encore pris la peine d'écrire un mot à M. de Charlus, je leur avais violemment reproché de vouloir me faire accepter des propositions déshonnêtes. Mais seuls la colère, le désir de trouver la phrase qui pouvait leur être le plus désagréable m'avaient dicté cette réponse mensongère. En réalité, je n'avais rien imaginé de sensuel, ni même de sentimental, sous les offres du baron. Proust,Sodome, 1922, p.639.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avance)) ♦ Absol. (souvent avec une coloration péj.). **Faire des avances. Avoir recours à des approches, à des manœuvres par lesquelles on cherche à séduire**
> • Les hommes de la sorte ont un défaut et un ridicule. Au fond, ils aiment les femmes, mais ils ne le leur disent jamais. Ils voudraient que les femmes leur sautassent au cou, leur fissent des avances. Ils consentent à être aimés d'elles. Renan, Drames philosophiques,L'Eau de jouvence, 1888, V, 1, p. 502.

Dans les deux entrées ci-dessus le texte en caractères gras est celui des définitions. Quels que soient les changements  plus ou moins récents qui ont pris place et qui ne sont pas pris en compte dans le dictionnaire, un fait fondamental s'impose : la proposition est un acte qui ne laisse aucun doute quant à son but, qui est formulé explicitement, alors que les avances ne sont pas exactement de cette nature. On déduit cela des mots « approches » et « manœuvres » ; les avances sont un préliminaire aux propositions, ce que l'on a appelé « la court » en ce qui concerne le rituel formel d'un âge révolu et qui correspond à la pratique  beaucoup moins formalisée qui s'y apparente et que de nos jours on appelle toujours « la court » (dans l'expression « faire la court »). Étant donné que l'une des deux personne demande la participation d'une autre dans un  acte « sexuel », il est à mon avis impossible de parler d'avance, sauf peut-être d'un point de vue, sarcastique, cynique, qui n'est probablement pas celui des phrases examinées. Donc, on ne retient que la seconde phrase en tant que possibilité de langue correcte.

Néanmoins, il n'est pas question dans ces phrases « d'avances » ou de « propositions », mais de « propositions *sexuelles* » et d'« avances *sexuelles* », et ce premier terme comprend un pléonasme. Il faudrait donc changer ce terme dans  la phrase.

- Cesse de lui faire des propositions, ça fait plusieurs fois que tu lui demandes si tu peux lui faire une fellation et qu’il la refuse. Je pense honnêtement que tu le poursuis de tes assiduités et que la situation frise le harcèlement sexuel.

L'examen des deux dernières phrases, qui sont similaires, montre qu'il n'existe pas un problème de choix entre les deux première (en fait, maintenant, la seconde après sa modification) et ces deux dernières. Le premier groupe aborde la question selon le point de vue de ce qu'est généralement appelée l'action (proposition) et le second selon le point de vue que cette  demande serait d'un type particulier (faire une faveur) plutôt que d'un autre (recevoir une faveur), et cela est de toute façon très mal établi, ou même pas établi du tout en cela qu'apparemment personne ne sera d'accord sur le fait qu'il s'agisse de faire une faveur ou d'en recevoir une (et il y aura probablement ceux qui considèrent qu'il s'agit d'une faveur mutuelle) ; néanmoins en supposant que dans le milieu concerné cela est clair, alors il n'y a aucun critère linguistique pour déterminer quelles phrases sont préférables, ce n'est plus qu'une question de gout personnel : « demander des faveurs sexuelles à qqn », « faire des demandes de faveurs sexuelles à qqn » et « solliciter les faveurs sexuelles de qqn » sont des termes équivalent du point de vue du sens.

Answer (score 0):

> Arrête de lui faire des avances, ça fait [plusieurs](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22886/la-grammaire/les-determinants/determinants-indefinis/sens-du-determinant-ou-du-pronom-indefini-plusieurs) fois que tu lui
> demandes si tu peux le sucer et qu’il refuse. Je pense honnêtement
> que ça frise le harcèlement sexuel.

Clair, direct, usuel et dans la norme sociolinguistique (Québec ; et le contexte n'est pas celui du salon littéraire.). La locution *faire des [avances](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/avance)* se passe de précisions dans le contexte. Je trouve *poursuivre quelqu'un de ses assiduités* particulièrement inusité et j'ai dû en vérifier le [sens](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/assiduit%C3%A9), possiblement péjoratif si bien choisi. Je choisis le verber [*sucer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sucer) plutôt que *faire une fellation*, inutile de mettre des gants blancs, a fortiori quand on s'adresse à un ami. Le tout permet d'aller droit au but, à l'oral...